# How do I place a background image in the exact center of another background image

Tags: css

I would like to place a background image in the exact center of another background image but I'm not sure to how to go about it.

My html is as follows

```
<body>
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
</body>
```

my css is:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}

.bg {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/mississauga.jpg');

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover, ;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to do here? Do you want to put an extra "background-image" to `.bg` class?

Answer (score 1):

```
 /*use this in html may be it will work 
         <body>
   <div class="bg">
        <div class="bg1">
        </div>
      </div>
   </body> */


   * {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
     }

     html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
```

}

```
    .bg {
      height: 100%;
       background-image: url('../images/mississauga.jpg');

       background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: cover, ;
         background-position: center;
        }

     .bg1
       { width:100%;
         height:100%;
           background: url('../images/mississauga.jpg') no-repeat center center;


          }
```